# Объединение коллайдеров

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Существует 5 квадратов 2d:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каждый из которых имеет свой собственный box collider:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: если таких квадратов будет 100 или 1000, можно ли как-то объединить коллайдеры всех этих квадратов в один при том, чтобы осталось взаимодействие с каждым из этих квадратов?

Comment: Что значить `объединить`, не понятно, но прикидывая что может подразумеваться... Нет нельзя!

Comment: Да, не очень понятно, в целом танцами с бубном можно, но будет много проблем, чуть больше опишите вопрос

Comment: @Yaroslav , понял вас